# XPath doesn't work as desired in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

My code doesn't return the node

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.InnerXml = text;

XmlNode node_ =  xml.SelectSingleNode(node);
return node_.InnerText; // node_ = null !
```

I'm pretty sure my XML and Xpath are correct.

My Xpath : `/ItemLookupResponse/OperationRequest/RequestId`

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05">
  <OperationRequest>
    <RequestId>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx</RequestId>
    <!-- the rest of the xml is irrelevant -->
  </OperationRequest>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

The node my XPath returns is always null for some reason. Can someone help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your XPath is almost correct - it just doesn't take into account the default XML namespace on the root node!

```
<ItemLookupResponse 
    xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05">
             *** you need to respect this namespace ***
```

You need to take that into account and change your code like this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.InnerXml = text;

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05");

XmlNode node_ = xml.SelectSingleNode(node, nsmgr);
```

And then your XPath ought to be:

```
 /x:ItemLookupResponse/x:OperationRequest/x:RequestId
```

Now, your node_.InnerText should definitely *not* be NULL anymore!

Comment: @Nick Brooks: no, if there is a XML namespace on the root element, then your XML elements below that are in that namespace, and thus you need to reference them using that namespace. That's the whole point of XML namespace - being able to distinguish XML elements of potential the same name, by putting them into application or vendor-specific namespaces.

Comment: The namespace can be added like this which is bit better than hard coding the namespace 
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

Comment: Um, can't we somehow set it up to either (A) automatically use all `xmlns` attributes, or (B) just tell .NET to ignore namespaces and match whatever we literally see in our XML file? Also, where does the string `"x"` come from?

Comment: @Qwertie: (A) no, and (B) no again. XML namespaces are there **for a reason** - you need to learn to respect them and work with them instead of trying to avoid them. The `x` is an arbitrary namespace prefix - could be `y` or whatever else you want - really just a prefix you pick (as a "shortcut" to your XML namespace)

Comment: Greet! Turns out that it's caused by name space for SelectNodes method!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply but I had a similar problem just a moment ago.

if you REALLY want to ignore that namespace then just delete it from the string you use to initialise the XmlDocument

```
text=text.Replace(
"<ItemLookupResponse xmlns=\"http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05\">",
"<ItemLookupResponse>");

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.InnerXml = text;

XmlNode node_ =  xml.SelectSingleNode(node);
return node_.InnerText;
```